# How to change the envelope status to "void" using java?

Tags: java, docusignapi

both the DNS and SVC are having some kind of scheduling system and the docusign interface has to void the status of the envelope when the scheduling system hits certain magic number. I just need the java method for changing the status into "void". Im aware that the documents cannot be declined and completed. But a void is a necessity to what im developing..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I hate to state the obvious, but just search for "void" in either the [SOAP](https://www.docusign.com/sites/default/files/DocuSignAPI_Guide.pdf) or [REST](https://www.docusign.com/sites/default/files/REST_API_Guide_v2.pdf) api documentation and  you'll see it.

**SOAP:**

```
SOAPAction: "http://www.docusign.net/API/3.0/VoidEnvelope"
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<soap:Envelope xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
 <soap:Body>
 <VoidEnvelope xmlns="http://www.docusign.net/API/3.0">
 <EnvelopeID>string</EnvelopeID>
 <Reason>string</Reason>
 </VoidEnvelope>
 </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```

**REST:**

```
PUT https://{server}/restapi/{apiVersion}/accounts/{accountId}/envelopes/
{envelopeId}
X-DocuSign-Authentication:
<DocuSignCredentials><Username>{name}</Username><Password>{password}</Password><Integrato
rKey>{integrator_key}</IntegratorKey></DocuSignCredentials>
Accept: application/json
Content-Type: application/json
{
"status":"voided",
"voidedReason":"voided for incorrect recipient"
}
```

Comment: im getting an error saying white spaces are required between publicId and systemId.

Comment: publicId and systemId aren't DocuSign values so I assume that error is in your application code, not being returned from DocuSign?

Comment: whitespace issue was solved, there was some missing values on the request. however, now, im getting a null point exception.

Comment: null point solved..getting a INVALID_CONTENT_TYPE ..is this to be changed in the request body?